# Email Validation is not working in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, validation

Guys i want to validate email address in php file "validate.php". But its not working. I am not getting any response back from "validate.php" file.

jQuery Code:

```
function validate_email(email){

         $.post('validate.php', {email:email}, function(data){

               $('msg').text(data);

           });
}

$('#input').focusin(function(){ 
  if($('#input').val() === ''){
     $('#msg').text("Enter Valid Email Address");
  }
  else{
       validate_email($('#input').val());
  }       
  }).blur(function(){ 
            $('#msg').text("");
}).keyup(function(){
            validate_email($('#input').val());
      });
```

"validate.php" code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){

   $email = $_POST['email']; 

   if(!empty($email)){
   if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
          echo 'Email Address is not Valid, Enter a Valid Email Address.';
   else
          echo 'Email is valid. Mubarak Ho!';

   }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Check your browser's JavaScript console for errors and inspect the network requests.

Answer (score 1):

Check the error log because your code work well on my server

This is my code test

#### HTML Part

```
<input id="email" type="email" value="dinhphong.developer@gmail.com">
<button>Submit</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    console.log(email);
    $.post('validate.php', {email:email}, function(data){
       console.log(data);
    });
})

</script>
```

#### PHP Part

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){

   $email = $_POST['email']; 

   if(!empty($email)){
   if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
          echo 'Email Address is not Valid, Enter a Valid Email Address.';
   else
          echo 'Email is valid. Mubarak Ho!';

   }
}
```

My advice:

- At `$('msg').text(data);` it should be `$('#msg').text(data);`
- F12 check error log of javascript
- Check php path on ajax by f12 -> network -> xhr and check status (if you use chrome)
- if status == 200 (it mean OK)  click to validate.php to check response from PHP file
- don't forget to feedback if you fixed your bug it can help another guy have same bug with you

Comment: Thanks for the advise, Problem solved. status == 200, M getting response from PHP file.
The only problem was that i didn't include # with $('msg').text(data);

Comment: @Hussam_Cheema Is it mean your bug got fix ? Congrats if yes